# Can a website tell a user's browser to store the entire page locally?

Tags: html, http, web, next.js, nuxt.js

Can a (single-page) website tell a user's browser to store an entire page locally?

For context: I'm hosting a website on a server that charges according to bandwidth. The contents of the site don't change much, so I'm wondering if the user's browser can store the webpage rather than sending repeat requests for the web page!

I've looked into browser-native cacheing, but that appears to be for further requests triggered after the page's scripts load!

Answer (score 1):

This is usually achieved thanks to PWA and Service workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Offline_Service_workers

Actually it's the only way of doing that I know, it can be a bit tricky but it's quite interesting once you understand everything that you can do with it.